# chart.js Hide empty Chart and keep previous data if no data? .net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, charts, chart.js

I have a chart where based on date, data changes. Problem current date is default and sometimes there is no data to show. is it possible with chart.js to check for if there is data in current chart and keep previous if there is none. Subing it with DIV placeholder ect. Same data is also in DataTable. Not really good at writing conditions yet.

Things I tried so far:

```
if (sampleTable != null && sampleTable.rows.count > 0) {
    $("#labelDiv").hide();
}


if (parsedData.Item2 = null)
{
    $("#labelDiv").hide();
}


if (buyerData == null) {
    $("#labelDiv").hide();
}

chart

var buyerData = {
    labels: parsedData.Item2,
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Lazi Chart",
            fillColor: "rgba(10,190,10,0.6)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: parsedData.Item3,
        }
    ]
}
barChartOptions.datasetFill = false;
barChart.Bar(barChartData, barChartOptions);
```

I figured it out. I check if object is empty and then if it is place a div saying experimental data and fake chart. Tnx for Any Help.

```
if (parsedData.Item1 != "") {
       $("#labelDiv").hide();
       $("#buyers").show();
                }
                else {
                    $("#labelDiv").show();
                    $("#FakeData").show();
                    $("#buyers").hide();

                    var barData = {
                        labels: ['SaaS', 'Virtual Machines', 'Networking', 'Storage', 'Data Managment'],
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: '2010 customers #',
                                fillColor: '#382765',
                                data: [2500, 1902, 1041, 610, 1245]
                            },
                            {
                                label: '2014 customers #',
                                fillColor: '#7BC225',
                                data: [3104, 1689, 1318, 589, 1199]
                            }
                        ]
                    };
                    var context = document.getElementById('FakeData').getContext('2d');
    var clientsChart = new Chart(context).Bar(barData);
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know chart.js, but by it's name I'll assume it's a plugin to draw graphs.

Probably, it'll require that you feed them with data, or at least, with an endpoint where read the data, so it can draw a graph that represent these data.

Now... if you have a data collection, or an endpoint where check for data, won't be easy to check these data and redirect your code execution than try to do that from within a plugin?

If the collection of data is empty or you don't get data from the endpoint just end the execution or return it to the last call (which you could have stored previously if necessary)

Comment: If you take a look at the code, he is providing the `barChart` with data already. This should really be a comment and not a answer.